# intl-tel-input is not displaying correctly on chrome

Tags: css, intl-tel-input

I'm using the intlTelInput feature for setting international mobile numbers and it's works well on Firefox.  However the CSS on Chrome is very off. See the image below.

How do I get the CSS in the intlTelInput.css file to work consistently on all browsers?

[image: CSS Issue]

Comment: Could you please provide the code block. It will help in understanding what you have done so far.

Comment: Hi @ManishPatel.  It was my silly mistake.  I had a the css path incorrect as I was adding versions as querystrings, so it refreshes on the clients side. and instead of ?v=3  i put >v=3 :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my CSS path query string value has '>v=3'  instead of '?v=3'

It's working fine now.